# AWS containers setup with static ip addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have a cluster in AWS Elastic container service.
This service runs 5-15 tasks from the same docker image in the same subnet.
For each task, AWS provides a unique IP address from the public pool.
I want to make this address static. These tasks using only outbound connections.
How can I do it?

Comment: Usually when you need static IP for outbound traffic you would use a NAT Gateway or multiple NAT Gateways, and route all your outbound traffic through those.

Comment: If you put all tasks in a private subnet, the outbound traffics move from the NAT gateway to the Internet and the IP of NAT GW is static (EIP)

Comment: @MarkB Can I add multiply NAT Gateways for one subnet? I need to access the same IP address for all my tasks.

Comment: Why do you need more than one outgoing static IP per subnet?

Comment: I have a limitation of requests per IP address. To increase this limit I want to use more IP addresses